# Drupal, Lightbox2, callback function?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, lightbox

is there any callback function for lightbox2 in Drupal ?

I need to trigger some functions when the lightbox content is ready

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

http://www.erikhedin.com/web-design/drupal-tips/Easy-Ajax-Nodes-Lightbox-Content

Comment: I've solved differently, adding the code directly in the loaded page. Yeah, this was what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Lightbox2 module?

http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2

It has a myriad of options to use. It also adds itself as a Views field option when displaying an image.

Comment: yeah I agree it has a lot of functions. Probably that's why I cannot find how to trigger a callback function when the content of the lightbox is loaded... I'm inspecting the code..

Answer (score 0):

Like this: [How to trigger event on arbitrary function call using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037120/how-to-trigger-event-on-arbitrary-function-call-using-jquery)