# How to trigger event on arbitrary function call using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox2

I'm wondering if it's possible to use jQuery's bind() to fire a custom event when an arbitrary function is called. Something like,

```
/* when cmsPlugin.func() is called, fire myCustom.func() too */
$.bind( cmsPlugin.func, myCustom.func );
```

We're using the Lightbox2 plugin for Drupal on a site.

When the lightbox is displayed, I want to fire some custom code which will attach to clicks on a "download" link in the Lightbox.

The Lightbox2 plugin doesn't appear to call $.trigger(), so I have a few options -

- Find a way to bind to javascript function calls. (In this case, Lightbox.end I believe.)
- Use an existing event, eg $(document).ready, which may (?) be fired as part of the lightbox display.
- Extend the existing function to add a $.trigger() call.
- Just hammer myCustom.func() repeatedly for a time after detecting that a lightbox-triggering element has been clicked. (Ewww.)
- __*_*__*_*__ ?

---

**Solution**

I attempted to simplify my question by using the cmsPlugin.func / myPlugin.func but I think I might have confused myself in doing so. However, I hope that the solutions posted will be generic enough for future readers to use themselves.

Thanks Adam and Lucho. I didn't have any luck with Lucho's suggestion, but I suspect that this was my own fault and not Lucho's :)

At first I tried Lucho's example code, modifying it to fire Drupal.zipcart.init() when Lightbox.updateNav was executed. This didn't work for me.

I decided on Lightbox.updateNav() to extend because it was a simple function called late in Lightbox2's display method.

My attempt at modifying Lucho's code looked like this, but didn't work -

```
// NOT THE RIGHT SOLUTION (for me)
Lightbox.updateNav = function(_dz, _lb) { return function() {
        _lb.updateNav();
        _dz.init();
    };
}(Drupal.zipcart, Lightbox);
```

Here's the code I ended up using based on Adam's answer, which allows Drupal's [ZipCart](http://drupal.org/project/zipcart) and [Lightbox2](http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2) modules to play nicely together, making links with class="zipcart" in the lightbox correctly add files to the download cart.

```
(function(){
  var _updateNav = Lightbox.updateNav;
  Lightbox.updateNav = function () {
    $(document).bind('lightbox.updateNav', function() {
      Drupal.zipcart.init();
    });
    $("#lightbox").trigger('lightbox.updateNav');
    _updateNav.apply(this, arguments);
  }
})();
$(document).bind('lightbox.updateNav', function () { Drupal.zipcart.init(); });
```

Comment: The bind call should be moved elsewhere, to separate the concerns between the updateNav function and your listener. I would also recommend using `delegate` instead because the lightbox markup won't exist at page load. `$(document).delegate('#lightbox', 'lightbox.updateNav', function () {})` will work regardless of how many times the lightbox markup is created or destroyed. Again, I don't know enough about the plugin to tell you exact how to select its markup.

Comment: Thanks, will look into `delegate` as well, although I see it's a recent addition to jQuery. I had spotted that the bind was in the wrong place. Might try `live` instead.

Comment: I don't need to bind to the specific #lightbox element, so I just associated the custom event with `document` instead. Code above updated; initially I had a `$().bind()` sitting inside the rewritten `Lightbox.updateNav` function.

Comment: If the lightbox markup is added to a particular section of your page, it would be better to attach the delegate to that -- attaching to `document` will work but the event has to bubble all the way to the top of the DOM before it gets triggered, so it will be slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You cannot bind event listeners to a function. Events are bound and triggered from DOM nodes, so you need to know how to select the lightbox's markup.</strike> *jQuery allows doing this now, but you still need a wrapper to trigger the event.*

The cleanest way I can think of to accomplish this would be to wrap the Lightbox.updateNav function and fire a custom event.

```
(function(){
  var _updateNav = Lightbox.updateNav;

  Lightbox.updateNav = function () {
    $("#lightbox").trigger('lightbox.updateNav');
    _updateNav.apply(this, arguments);
  }
})();
```

`#lightbox` needs to point to the lightbox markup that you can bind event listeners to. I don't know enough about LightBox2's API to tell you how to do this exactly.

This is better than a simple wrapper function because you can wire up as many listeners as you like.

```
$("#lightbox").bind('lightbox.updateNav', function() {})
```

Since the lightbox markup is likely created and destroyed dynamically, you would be better off using `delegate` instead (provided you have access to jQuery 1.4.2). If you can identify where the markup is inserted, attach a delegate to the parent element:

```
$('#lightbox-parent').delegate('#lightbox', 'lightbox.updateNav', function() {})
```

This is much better performance than `.live()` so I would recommend doing it this way if you can.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I tried both this and Lucho's modified answer below. Yours worked and is much appreciated. I'll update the question with my final code now.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmsPlugin.func = function(myCustom, cmsPlugin) { return function() {
        cmsPlugin.func();
        myCustom.func();
    };
}(myCustom, cmsPlugin);
```

Comment: Thanks, will give this a shot now :)

Comment: I just added a second parameter to the first anon func, I think it might be needed.

Comment: I had no luck with this. Here's the modified version I was trying - I probably confused things by trying to make my question generic.